# Get the full substring matching the regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am not good with regular expressions and was looking at some online resources for what I would like to do. So basically, I have a regular expression in Python as follows:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?)(?=TAG|TGA|TAA))')
```

This is supposed to find all sub strings which begin with ATG and end in TAG or TGA or TAA. I use it as:

```
str = "ATGCCCTAG"
print pattern.findall(str)
```

However, this returns `ATGCCC` and removes the trailing `TAG` and I would like it to keep the trailing `TAG`. How can I change it to give me the full substring?

Comment: I think you are actually looking for [`^ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)$`](https://regex101.com/r/wI7hT9/2).

Comment: No, it does not have to start with ATG. Can be a substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a simpler regex without lookahead, i.e.:

```
re.compile("ATG(?:...).*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)")
```

---

**DEMO:**

https://regex101.com/r/qI4fV0/3

---

**EXPLANATION:**

```
ATG(?:...).*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)

ATG matches the characters ATG literally (case sensitive)
(?:...) Non-capturing group
    . matches any character (except newline)
    . matches any character (except newline)
    . matches any character (except newline)
.*? matches any character (except newline)
    Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
(?:TAG|TGA|TAA) Non-capturing group
    1st Alternative: TAG
        TAG matches the characters TAG literally (case sensitive)
    2nd Alternative: TGA
        TGA matches the characters TGA literally (case sensitive)
    3rd Alternative: TAA
        TAA matches the characters TAA literally (case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 3):

> To find all sub strings which begin with ATG and end in TAG or TGA or TAA

You will need a

```
ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)
```

This regex also makes sure there are 0 or more 3-symbol (excl. newline) sequences in-between `ATG` and the last `TAG`, `TGA` or `TAA`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA8fU7/2)

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/TLsbiF):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)')
test_str = "FFG FFG ATGCCCTAG"
print (p.findall(test_str))
```

This will work if you need to find *non-overlapping* substrings. To find overlapping ones, the technique is to encapsulate that into a capturing group and place in a non-anchored positive look-ahead:

```
r'(?=(ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)))'
  |  |                           ||
  |  | --- Capture group ------- ||   
  | -- Positive look-ahead ------ |
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ7iH0/1)

Answer (score 2):

You seems to not well understand what a lookahead is. A lookahead is a *zero-width* assertion and means *"the current position in the string is followed by"*, in other words, it matches nothing since it's only a test. Consequence, the content tested in the second lookahead, will not be a part of the capture group 1 even if you put it inside. Note that `re.findall` returns a non-empty result only because it returns the capture groups content.

If you want to include it in the capture group 1, remove the second lookahead and put the end in the capture group:

```
(?=(ATG(?:...)*?(?:TAG|TGA|TAA)))
```

The interest of putting a whole pattern in a lookahead and a capture group is to get overlapping results. For example `ATGCCCATGCCCTAG` will return `ATGCCCATGCCCTAG` and `ATGCCCTAG`.

If you remove it, you will only obtain `ATGCCCATGCCCTAG`